# Can't remove or unbind this document.addEventListener

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I am modifying an HTML5 app that contains the following code to prevent scrolling on one of the screens:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (evnt) { evnt.preventDefault(); }, false);
```

I can't get scrolling to come back afterwards on the other screens - I've looked through multiple answers about `removeEventListener` and have tried:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (evnt) { return true; }, false);

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (evnt) { evnt.preventDefault(); }, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot remove or unbind an anonymous function. (Your callback for the touchmove event).

However, you could easily achieve what you want with a variable that has reference to a function.  See below:

```
var callback = function (evnt) { evnt.preventDefault(); };    
document.addEventListener('touchmove', callback, false);
document.removeEventListener('touchmove', callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you bind to `touchmove` on a child element of the `document` (maybe the page's container, whatever that may be), then do `evnt.stopPropagation()` in that event handler, the event will never bubble up to the document and will not get prevented.

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (evnt) { evnt.preventDefault(); }, false);

child.addEventListener('touchmove', function (evnt) { evnt.stopPropagation(); }, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an anonymous function, give it a name

```
    var blockScroll = function(evnt) {
        evnt.preventDefault();
    }
```

Then you can add it as a listener:

```
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', blockScroll);
```

And you can later remove it as a listener:

```
    document.removeEventListener('touchmove', blockScroll);
```